# the ampersand does not show in second field in segment MSH using hl7apy Field

Tags: python, hl7-v2

I was trying to create segment MSH in a HL7 message

```
from hl7apy.core import Message, Segment, Field

def create_msh():
    msh = Segment("MSH")
    msh_2 = Field("msh_2")
    msh_2.value = "^~\&"
    msh.add(msh_2)
    print(msh.value)
    return msh

create_msh()
```

The print result is:

```
MSH|^~\
```

Do not know why the last symbol ampersand & is NOT added to the second field in MSH segment. How to fix this issue?
Your help is appreciated.

Regards,
Arthur

Comment: I have probably spent too much time looking at this, but I think when you are adding the value, it is treating the `&` as a subcomponent separator and not as part of the value defining the subcomponent separator.  I haven't been able to figure out how to escape it.  If you make a Message that includes the MSH segment such as Message("ADT_A01"), then the MSH segment is automatically created for you with the 2nd field automatically set as expected.  I suspect there is some special handling based on the traversal_parent but I have not untangled it all yet.